# trying to find a way to bash script my results

Tags: bash, shell, automated-tests, unreal-engine4

I have a `testResultOuput.txt` which contains lines that look like this:

```
[2022.03.03-13.28.59:742][394]LogAutomationController: Error: Test Completed. **Result={Failed}** **Name={MyAwesomeTest}** Path={AutoTests.UnitTests}
[2022.03.03-13.28.59:742][394]LogAutomationController: BeginEvents: AutoTests.UnitTests
[2022.03.03-13.28.59:742][394]LogAutomationController: Error: Expected 'MyAwesomeTest' to be 0.000000, but it was -2147483648.000000 within tolerance 0.000100.
```

and so far I find these lines with: `& grep Result={Failed} testResultOuput.txt`

anyone can help?

I want to write a shell script to search by Result and print only the `Name={}` and `Result={}` from these lines

Comment: You can use the `-o` option. For example `grep -e 'Result={[^}]*}' -e 'Name={[^}]*}'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try `--only-matching` grep option, which will output only matched part :

```
-o, --only-matching
       Print only the matched (non-empty) parts  of  a  matching  line,
       with each such part on a separate output line.
```

For example:

```
grep --only-matching 'Result={[[:alpha:]]*} Name={[[:alpha:]]*}'
```

will output with your example:

```
$ grep --only-matching 'Result={[[:alpha:]]*} Name={[[:alpha:]]*}' foo
Result={Failed} Name={MyAwesomeTest}
$
```

**EDIT**, following different requirement in comments. If `result` and `name` are separated by undefined sequence of characters, and `{...}` replaced with `"..."`, for example :

```
result="Failed" [2022.03.03-13.28.59:742][394]LogAutomationController: Error: Test Completed. name="MyAwesomeTest"
```

I would use `sed` instead of `grep`. Something like :

```
sed -nE 's/(\bresult="[[:alpha:]]*").*(\bname="[[:alpha:]]*")/\1 \2/p'
```

Comment: you sir are a brilliant human being :D follow up question! if my result is looks like so -> result="Failed" how would you do that?

Comment: @TheoHexer, for Result="Failed", just replace `Result={[[:alpha:]]*}` with `Result="[[:alpha:]]*"`

Comment: i tried it and it didnt work :/ i think the "" are messing it up

Comment: It works for me (be sure to use single quotes (`'`) around the grep expression). If you use double quotes (`"`), you must escape the quotes inside with a backslash (`\"`).

Comment: if i run result and name seperately they work but together it doesnt work

Comment: What is your exact `grep` command (with quotes) ? It should be something like: `grep -o 'Result="[[:alpha:]]*" Name={[[:alpha:]]*}'`. Also, with my regex, `Name` must immediately follow `Result` with exactly **one space** in-between.

Comment: i adjusted it to this -> grep --only-matching 'result="[[:alpha:]]*" Name={[[:alpha:]]*}' 
but it doesnt seem to produce any output but when i run the result or the Name seperately it works

Comment: Please edit your question with your exact input data and quote requirement (and confirm `Result` becomes `result`).

Comment: @TheoHexer, I just noticed you changed the input data with `**` before and after the `Result` and `Name` parts. Are stars part of the input ?

Comment: i think i am confusing you! i am sorry :P i ll simplify

[2022.03.03-13.28.59:742][394]LogAutomationController: Error: Test Completed. result="Failed" name="MyAwesomeTest" path="AutoTests.UnitTests"

what would be the grep command to get name and result in this line case :)

Comment: It should be: `grep -o 'result="[[:alpha:]]*" name="[[:alpha:]]*"'`.

Comment: hmmm again when i pass result or name seperately it works but together i get no output
grep -o 'result="[[:alpha:]]*"' <- this works
grep -o 'name="[[:alpha:]]*"' <- this works
grep -o 'result="[[:alpha:]]*" name="[[:alpha:]]*"' <- this no output

any ideas?

Comment: It could be for example 2 spaces before name, this kind of thing... I have no other clue without the exact input file.

Comment: very strange....

Comment: wait i get it what if the line looks like this ->> result="Failed" [2022.03.03-13.28.59:742][394]LogAutomationController: Error: Test Completed. name="MyAwesomeTest" path="AutoTests.UnitTests"

Comment: Then try : `grep -o -e 'result="[[:alpha:]]*"' -e 'name="[[:alpha:]]*"' foo.txt`. But output will be on 2 lines.

Comment: But for complicated expressions like that, I personally use `sed`: `sed -nE 's/(result="[[:alpha:]]*").*(name="[[:alpha:]]*")/\1 \2/p'`

Comment: i think this command did it  grep -o 'result="[[:alpha:]]*".*name=""[[:alpha:]]*"    but for some reason it doesnt print everything i have in the file do you have any documentation on this or can you explain to me what exactly you are doing here?

Comment: as i understand it it doesnt check those 2 words and printing the alpha it also prints other stuff in between

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you get, but we are at the limits of `grep` here : The `-o` option will display the matching part. However, everything between result and name is part of the matching string. You may use multiple `-e`, but lines with only one of result or name will match too. The best is to use `sed` (or awk, etc...) here, as we can display part of the matching string only.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```sh
$ grep -o '\<Result={[^}]*} Name={[^}]*}' testResultOutput.txt
Result={Failed} Name={MyAwesomeTest}
```